# Mingw-W64 is downloaded as a winrar file not as an installer.exe and even i can't install it as a winrar when i extract it

Tags: mingw-w64

I want to install Mingw-W64, but the download is in winrar form not in a `.exe`. When I extract, it the folder is filled with bunch of files. None of them contains the installer.

I searched, but nothing is working. All I want is the installer.exe but every time it's just an archive.

I found a video, but there is a problem when I tried the instructions. The download kept restarting and nothing happened. When I extracted the archive the files are not same as shown in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a windows installer at the msys2 official website https://www.msys2.org/ . Follow the guides for a successful installation.

Alternatively you need to extract the downloaded files to a path like the root of your C: drive and add the contents to your system or user path as an environment variable.